# About leakage current, standby current and current budgeting

Tags: flash, non-volatile-memory

Am using ST microelectronics NAND Flash device [NAND01GW3A0AN6E](http://doc.chipfind.ru/pdf/stmicroelectronics/nand01gw3a0an6e.pdf).

In this datasheet under Dc characteristics table they specified leakage current,standby current,operating current parameters.

1. What is known as input leakage current IL and output leakage current OL ?the test conditions are given as Vin=0 to Vdd max for Il and Vout=0 to Vdd max for OL
2. Why TTL standby current is in milliamps and CMOS standby current is in nanoamps?Test condition is CE#= High level input voltage for TTL logisc and CE# = Vdd- 0.2
3. NAND flash has three operations read, program, erase and each operation drives some current.For example Read current=5mA, Program current= 7mA, Erase current= 7 mA.

Let us consider a scenario where the device is first in standby mode and it is programmed,read and erased sequentially.How to do find out the total current driven by the device?

Comment: You ask a lot of questions about a datasheet that you don't link to, you don't even mention the chip. We are engineers, not crystal ball gazers!

Comment: Added a datasheet link, replace with a more appropriate one if you like.

Answer (score 1):

In general, inputs are ideally regarded to be sensitive voltage only, with infinite input resistance. Of course, real devices have finite impedances, and the current that flows into or out of them is called "input leakage current".

Similarly, some outputs can be switched off or "tristated", and in this state, they're supposed to have infinite resistance as well. But again, real devices have finite resistances, and the current that flows into or out of them is called "output leakage current".

If you want to talk about power consumption of a particular device, you'll have to provide more detail about the device in question. In general, you'll need to look up how much current it draws in each of its different modes of operation (e.g., sleep, standby, reading, writing), and multiply these values by the percentage of time it's going to spend in each of those modes in your particular application, then add up those products to get a total.